# Insert a C# List + mixed values to database using Dapper.NET

Tags: list, dapper

Is it possible to insert a list of values and mixed values using [dapper](/questions/tagged/dapper) in the samme command? Assuming that all properties match SQL parameters and:

```
private class MyObject
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    public string B { get; set; }
}

private class YourObject
{
    public int C { get; set; }
}

private List<MyObject> myObjectList;
private List<YourObject> yourObjectList;
```

This works:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO <table1> VALUES (@A, @B);";
connection.Execute(query, myObjectList);
```

This also works:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO <table2> VALUES (@C)";
connection.Execute(query, yourObjectList);
```

But I would like to have something like:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO <table1> VALUES (@A, @B); INSERT INTO <table2> VALUES (@C)";
connection.Execute(query, myObjectList, yourObjectList );
```

Comment: I can't see what you would gain from that. It's much cleaner to keep the inserts apart. If you need the operation to be atomic use a transaction.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have a sql function that calculates something from me that I would like to use in the same query. Yes I am using a transaction

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use storedprocedure to do that.
in DB create procedure like that;
<pre>   <i> create procedure sp_dowork
    declare @A int,
    declare @B int,
    declare @C int
    as
    INSERT INTO <table1> VALUES (@A, @B);
    INSERT INTO <table2> VALUES (@C);
    end
</pre>
then call procedure from your code like this.
<pre>
    string q = "sp_dowork";
    connection.Execute(q, myObjectList, yourObjectList)
</pre>
This should work.
```